# Fixing different cursor sizes in unity

Tags: 14.10, macbook-pro, cursor

I'm running ubuntu 14.10 on a macbook pro with retina display (2560x1600)

I have set "Scale for menu and titlebars" in Sytem Settings --> Display to 1.75 which scales up fine.

The cursor however behaves rather weird:

- In unity and when resizing windows it is tiny and hard to use
- In applications such as firefox, terminal it has a reasonable size

What does cause this "two cursor sizes" and how can I fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have that setting at 1.0 and see the opposite: a larger than usual arrow cursor over the title bar, certain applications including File Roller, and the Desktop; and large cursors when resizing/moving windows. Setting Scale=1.38 results in the same large cursor all over.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, upgrading to 15.04 solved it.

Documentation on the process can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VividUpgrades)